# Should I use a database column to replace a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, methods

My app uses a method that is called many many times during an important event, so that it affects performance.

Can I improve the design by using a database column instead?  The column would hold the same integer that was outputted by the old method, but it would calculate the value ahead of time, instead of during the critical event.  The downside is that I would need to update the column during a lot of other, less-common events.

Does this design go against best practice?  Would a professional rails developer hate this approach?  Is there something that I might be unaware of that could be better than both approaches?

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: This really just boils down to the cost of computing the value vs the cost of the updates. There is no best practice here - use the right tool for the job and remember “Premature optimization is the root of all evil”.

Comment: Sounds like you could do with some caching. The best advice I have is to ensure you have a suitable test suite before you try to start optimising things. There's no substitute for metrics.

Comment: That makes sense.  These comments helped me to see that I'm not as noob as I thought I was.